# Example of Logistic Regression using a proportion as the dependent variable?

Tags: python, logistic-regression

[image: sample data]

I am trying to run a logistic regression on a data set where my dependent variable is a proportion of a binary variable, rather than the binary variable itself.  I have seen a ton of documentation that says this is possible, but I am having trouble finding an example of how to actually do it.  I am open to using scikit learn, statsmodels, or any other library that will do it.

I have added a photo showing a simplified version of my data.

`successes` here is just a count of a binary (1/0) outcome.  instead of having the individual observations, I only have them rolled up, but my understanding is that it is still a logistic regression problem.  I want to predict the dependent variable 'proportion' based on the features.  I understand this conceptually, but am just trying to find an example of this in python.  all of the examples I have seen assume a binary dependent variable.

your help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just binomial regression - see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208213/logistic-regression-with-binomial-data-in-python Note the inputs there are *not* just the proportion but the two columns of attempts and successes, because the more attempts there are, the lower the variance on the estimate of the proportion.

Comment: I think this could be on topic here or on Cross Validated. It's in the overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the link by @Spacedman shows, binomial regression works well. If you don't have the attempts and successes but, instead, have just the proportion, then you'll want to use beta-regression. After a little digging, it doesn't seem like this is available in Python. [Here's a blog post demoing it in R](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2014/01/generalized-linear-models-for-predicting-rates/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=generalized-linear-models-for-predicting-rates).

Comment: I do have the attempts and successes, as shown in my data pic.  I'd really like to do the logistic regression, not the binomial regression.  And I def can't do it in R. I have talked to two data scientists who were convinced this was possible in Python, but they didn't know where to find a specific example.

Comment: Then what @Spacedman linked you to is the correct path. Alternatively, you could predict whether or not a single *observation* was a success or not, which is where you could use Logistic Regression. To do that, you'd have to unfold the data from group 1, ..., to Observation 1 in Group 1, Observation 2 in Group 1, etc.

Comment: @tarastar42 perhaps you should have talked to two statisticians instead of data scientists. There's no point doing this as a logistic regression unless you have individual level features (ie they were possibly different for each trial). Its not a logistic regression, its a binomial regression, in the same way that modelling count data (eg number of cars past the bus stop every minute) is a Poisson regression. These are all just types of Generalised Linear Model.

Comment: @Spacedman hits the nail on the head, you really shouldn't model it as a Logistic regression because it just increases the computational cost and understates the uncertainty of your predictions (since it'll artificially increase your sample size). You certainly *can* do it but it's like using a wrench to hammer in a nail; it works but isn't the best tool for the job.